# Find triple duplicates in the array JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

Current code doesn't work. I want to alert all sequences of 3 equal numbers.

```
function myFunction() {
    var fruits = [3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8, 9];
    var a = fruits.sort();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
    for(var i = 0, j = 1, k = 2; i < fruits.length, j < fruits.length, k < fruits.length; i++, j++, k++){
        if(fruits[i].valueOf() == fruits[j].valueOf() == fruits[k].valueOf()){
            alert(fruits[i].valueOf()+" "+fruits[j].valueOf() +" "+fruits[k].valueOf());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this option:

```
for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
    if(fruits[i] === fruits[i+1] && fruits[i] === fruits[i+2]){
       //msg
       alert('found!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm you can do like this but as of v0.0.1 works only for single digits.

```js
var fruits = [3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8, 9, 6, 6, 6],
    triple = fruits.join("").match(/(\d)\1\1/g).map(e=>e.split("").map(e=>e*1));

document.write(JSON.stringify(triple));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var fruits = [3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8, 9];
var a = fruits.sort();

var cursor = 0;
var arraySize = fruits.length;
while(cursor < arraySize - 3){
 //big step:
  if(a[cursor] == a[cursor + 1] && a[cursor] == a[cursor + 2]){
    console.log(a[cursor]);
    cursor = cursor + 3;    
    continue;  
   }
 //medium step:
  if(a[cursor] == a[cursor + 1]){
    cursor = cursor + 2;
    continue;  
  }

  cursor++;
}
```

it's output will be 3 (as there are 3 consecutive appearances of the element)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
if(( fruits[i+1] !== null ) && (fruits[i] === fruits[i+1])) {
    if(( fruits[i+2] !== null ) && (fruits[i] === fruits[i+2])) {
          // your message 
          alert('');
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using an unordered extended example array, `Array.slice`, `Array.indexOf` and `Array.some` functions:

```
function myFunction() {
    var fruits = [3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 9, 7, 9],
        len = fruits.length, k = 0, notEqual = false, sequence;

    fruits.sort();
    while (k <= len) {
        sequence = fruits.slice(k, k + 3);
        if (sequence.length < 3) break;
        notEqual = sequence.some((v, k, arr) => arr.indexOf(v) !== 0);
        if (!notEqual) {   // check if all numbers in the sequence are equal
            console.log(sequence);
            k += 2;
        } else {
            k += 1;
        }
    }
}

myFunction();
```

The output:

```
[3, 3, 3]
[9, 9, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two main problem in code

1) If condition in loop:

```
if(fruits[i].valueOf() == fruits[j].valueOf() == fruits[k].valueOf())
```

This condition will be always false because when it compare with two values result will be false or true then again that false and true will be compared with value which will be false every time i.e (true===3) result : false

2) I can see you are using in alerts valueOf method which you dont need you can use directly fruits[i] to get value.

```
function myFunction() {
var fruits = [3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8, 9];
var a = fruits.sort();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
for(var i = 0, i < fruits.length-3;i++){

        if((fruits[i] == fruits[i+1]) &&(fruits[i]== fruits[i+2])){
        alert(fruits[i]+" "+fruits[i+1] +" "+fruits[i+2]);
    }
}}
```